# FormatException (FormatException: Trying to read from 02:38 at position 6)

Tags: flutter, dart

can anybody help me with my problem ? , i have this problem when i entering the time and choose the daily repeat the error was "FormatException (FormatException: Trying to read   from 02:38 at position 6)"

the error come from here

```
 if (task.repeat == 'Daily') {
        DateTime date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime.toString());
        var myTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
        notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
            int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[0]),
            int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[1]),
            task);
```

please help me with my problem

Comment: `jm` expects a 12-hour time, so it expects "AM" or "PM" in the string.  If you want a read a 24-hour time, you should be using `Hm`.  But if your input string is intended to be a 24-hour time, then your code is very roundabout (it parses a 24 hour time to a `DateTime`, reformats it to a 24-hour time string, and then manually parses it back again).

Comment: sorry i didn't get it

Comment: Didn't get which part?

Comment: "But if your input string is intended to be a 24-hour time, then your code is very roundabout (it parses a 24 hour time to a DateTime, reformats it to a 24-hour time string, and then manually parses it back again)." from here , actually i already make the time picker but at that the AM and PM doen't came out * sorry for my bad english

Comment: You don't need the `myTime` variable at all and can just use `notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(date.hour, date.minute, task);`.

Comment: For String manipulation, due the hour and minute methods return int, is important to add some leading zeroes to avoid exceptions like:
09:05 am => a string will be '9:5', but the correct is '09:05'. So change to `notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(date.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0'), date.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0'), task);`